# Lista resultados zerados na consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia pessoal,
Preciso da ajuda de vocês em um select, estou fazendo uma pesquisa, tenho uma 4 tabelas: usuario, pergunta, alternativas e resposta.
Na tabela resposta eu salvo o cpf do usuario, o id da pergunta e o id das alternativas, o que eu quero e contar quantos votos determinada alternativa recebeu, e retornar o valor com o titulo da alternativa, até ai tudo bem, o problema e que não consigo retornar as questões com nenhum voto, utilizando um outer join deu certo parcialmente, se eu mostrar todas, retorna as zeradas, porem, se eu filtrar pra uma pergunta especifica ele retorna apenas as questões com votos, como eu faço para retornar todos os valores inclusive os zerados.

tabela resposta:

```
create table tb_resposta (
cpf_usuario varchar(14) not null,
id_pergunta int not null,
id_resposta int not null,
foreign key (cpf_usuario) references tb_usuario(cpf),
foreign key (id_pergunta) references tb_pergunta(id),
foreign key (id_resposta) references tb_alternativa(id)
);
```

SELECT:

```
select a.titulo, count(r.id_resposta), r.id_pergunta from tb_resposta as r
right join tb_alternativa as a on a.id = r.id_resposta
where r.id_pergunta = 2
group by a.titulo;
```

no select acima, se eu tirar o where ele mostra todas inclusive as zeradas, porém com o where, não mostra.

as demais tabelas:

```
create table tb_pergunta (
    id int auto_increment not null primary key,
    titulo varchar (100)
);

create table tb_alternativa (
    id int auto_increment not null primary key,
    titulo varchar (100),
    id_pergunta int not null,
    foreign key (id_pergunta) references tb_pergunta(id)
);

create table tb_usuario (
    cpf varchar(14) not null primary key,
    idade int not null,
    sexo enum ('M', 'F') not null
);
```

Exemplo mais detalhado de como eu desejo a saída:
Imagem que tem a questão agência bancária, com as alternativas, banco do brasil, bradesco, itau, caixa e que só o banco do brasil e a caixa tenha sido votadas, o retorno que eu quero é:

Banco do Brasil - 1, Caixa - 1, Bradesco - 0, Itau - 0.

Comment: Como ficam salvas as respostas sem alternativa marcada? Seria interessante que você colocasse um exemplo de dados do banco para que fique claro como seus dados são persistidos em cada caso.

Comment: Troca o RIGHT JOIN por INNER JOIN.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra na tabela responsta fica salvo CPF - ID_PERGUNTA - ID_RESPOSTA.

Comment: @EliseuB. Não funciona, já tentei também.

Comment: Não entendi qual o resultado esperado. É para retornar apenas quantas vezes uma alternativa foi marcada o seu título? Por que existe o retorno do id da pergunta que está fora do group by?

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim por exemplo, existe a alternativa bancos por exemplo, ai lá vai ter sei lá, banco do brasil, caixa, itau e bradesco, vamos supor que só banco do brasil e itau foi votado, então eu quero retornar, banco do brasil - 1, itau - 1, bradesco - 0, caixa - 0, já tentei adicionar os campos no group by e mesmo assim não retorna como eu quero.

Comment: veja se ajuda https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/462564-selecionar-todos-os-dias-do-m%C3%AAs-e-quantidade-de-vendas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema, adicionando mais algumas condições na clausula where, ficou assim:

```
select a.titulo, count(r.id_resposta), r.id_pergunta from tb_resposta 
as r
right join tb_alternativa as a on a.id = r.id_resposta
where (r.id_pergunta = 2 and r.id_pergunta is not null) or 
(r.id_pergunta is null and a.id_pergunta = 2)
group by a.titulo;
```

Ele verifica a tabela resposta, pelo id, se o campo for nulo ele busca o id na tabela alternativa, que possui o id da pergunta, assim eu consigo listar todos as alternativas, inclusive com as zeradas.